# How is ISKCON different from Chinmaya Mission?

Tags: philosophy, vedanta, iskcon, prabhupada

How is the **philosophy** followed by **Iskcon** different from **Chinmaya Mission**?

Comment: Your question is too broad. Chinmaya Mission follow the advaita philosophy as popularized by Shankaracharya and interpreted by Swami Chinmayananda Saraswati. ISKCON follow the dvaita philsophy popularized by Madhva, interpreted by Chaitanya, and popularized in the last century by A. C. Bhaktivedanta Swami Prabhupada. To understand some of the basic differences in these philosophical systems, see https://archive.org/details/IndianPhilosophyACriticalSurvey and 'A History of Indian Philosophy' here - https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Your comment essentially answers this question. Maybe you can write a summary-like answer similar to your comment. If someone asks the same question in future, we may flag such questions as duplicates of this. Unless of course, all such questions gets closed for being too broad, then it's not needed :)